# BASE64DecoderStream.decode returns different values on different computers

Tags: java, encryption, base64

I have this java function that receives a string (str) and decodes it:

```java
public static String decrypt(String str) {
    try {
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode("seluR/beWhR=");
        key = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "DES");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] dec = BASE64DecoderStream.decode(str.getBytes());
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.update(dec, 0, dec.length);
        return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

When the function receives this value: `JLMcNWcDwNJS1MVO3Urhgco2ZQzk2EBc`

Returns this from my computer: `29/07/2022 16:19`

Returns this from my client's computer: `29/07/2022 16:19:10.12`

As you can see, values are very similar but they're different (the latter has 6 extra characters)

I don't understand why is this happening. The values should be exactly the same, isn't it? Both computers use the same JDK version (1.8). Both computers have Windows (I don't know if they're different, but it should matter).

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: To avoid truncation of the last part, replace `update()` by `doFinal()` and in `getInstance()` `"DES"` by `"DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"` (otherwise provider dependent default values are applied). Also only one Base64 implementation should be used (not a bug, but inefficient/unclean). Note, that DES and ECB are insecure.

Comment: There was a hint in that the shorter version is exactly 16 characters, that is 2 DES blocks. You were losing the third block of the decrypted text.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Topaco !! it worked!! About the Base64 implementation, there's only one I think (the other one is BASE64DecoderStream). Could you post your comment as an answer so I can marked as the correct answer here?